# How do I undo a thumbs down on Pandora?

Tags: pandora, music, streaming

I accidentally gave a thumbs down to a song I really like. Does anyone know how to undo a thumbs down for a song on Pandora's website?

**Edit**: I can't reach the song in my immediate history

Comment: Why can't you reach the song?

Comment: @sirconnorstack my immediate history. ;)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. Go to www.pandora.com
2. Go to the station in question
3. Right below station name on the list click "options". Here's an example from one of my stations: [musicforhackers](http://www.pandora.com/stations/aa3e5107c30d90342377005d24500e65fc083eb2d8dfd754).
4. Scroll down to the section titled " Thumbed-down Songs "
5. Find the song in question, and delete it from the "Thumbed-down Songs" section.
6. (iOS app): tap and hold desired thumbs down song for removal - a red 'delete' button will appear.

Comment: This is true on the website...on a computer. But mobile devices automatically switch to the app or the app download page. I even downloaded Chrome to try and reach the real website. No such luck.

Comment: @Felix - You can access Pandora website using Firefox on Android. Make sure you have Adobe Flash installed, then turn on "Desktop mode" or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote and asked about it to Pandora, this was the reply and it does work.

When you want to edit your station in any way, roll-over the station you'd like to edit, click the arrow next to options, then select Station Details.

On the station page, scroll down and you will see the Thumbs-up and Thumbs-down. By checking the x to the right of the song name, the song will go back go into the neutral pot.

Answer (score -1):

When you press one of your Pandora stations, there is an "Options" button. Press that and then tap "Station Details". There's a list of Thumbed-down tracks. I was able to select a track i accidentally disliked and like it.

Comment: This appears to duplicate the answer marked as correct over 2 years ago

Answer (score -2):

Give it a Thumbs Up, if you can reach it in your history.

Comment: Where can this be found? Try to elaborate a bit more so that the OP understands, but other readers as well.