# Thumbs Down Issue on Pandora

Tags: pandora

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I undo a thumbs down on Pandora?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/235/how-do-i-undo-a-thumbs-down-on-pandora)

So i just recently "thumbs down" a song i really like on pandora, but i did it on my ipod.
I already tried to go to pandora.com on my laptop to fix this issue by going to the station artists and removing my mistake. I went to the station and it didn't even have a subject called "Thumbs down" it just said "Thumbs up" songs. I was already very angry because pandora is already a difficult website to navigate around with all of the pop ups and long lasting loading pages. I just want to undo my mistake but i feel like i am stuck. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Keep scrolling down and you'll see the thumbs down list.

Comment: I have just had this same issue. I don't see any thumbs down list. I have clicked just about everything on the website and scrolled down to the bottom. I just emailed the help link and hopefully they'll be able to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote and asked about it to Pandora, this was the reply and it does work.

When you want to edit your station in any way, roll-over the station you'd like to edit, click the arrow next to options, then select Station Details.

On the station page, scroll down and you will see the Thumbs-up and Thumbs-down. By checking the x to the right of the song name, the song will go back go into the neutral pot.