# Can I undo Likes in Pandora?

Tags: pandora

Today, I had an odd urge to purge all of my Pandora history and start from fresh.  Many of my stations have become overly repetitive, so I figured re-doing my whole profile from a clean slate would help introduce new music into the mix.

My first step was to just delete all my stations.  That was easy enough.  But then, when playing through songs on a new station, I noticed Pandora still retained data on songs I'd Liked.  Since this probably will also influence Pandora's song choices, and I want to re-start totally fresh, I'm trying to find a way to undo all of my Likes.

I've found the screen that allows me to view my Likes in Pandora.  You simply go to your Profile and select Likes.  However, I don't see an option in this screen or in any of the drop-downs that allows me to un-Like a song.

Is there something I'm missing, or does this feature not exist?

Comment: Related: [How do I undo a thumbs down on Pandora?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/235)

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the options link for the station in question then click on station details and it will list station seeds, thumbed-up songs and thumbed-down songs for that station. All the way to the right of each thumbed-up song there is an X. If you click on the X it will remove that thumbs-up.